# ¿``Nomenclatura'' o ``Terminología''?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, definiciones

Me preguntaba cuál es la diferencia entre las palabras ''nomenclatura'' y ''terminología'' y cuál sería más apropiada en el contexto en que la usaría.

Me quiero referir a la forma de llamarle a cierto concepto/objeto (matemático). Un ejemplo concreto sería el título de una lista que enumere nombres alternativos para este. También podría ser una lista que enumere distintos objetos y su forma de llamarles más habitual.

Viendo las definiciones del DRAE no encuentro ninguna diferencia, sinceramente.

> nomenclatura
>
> 1. f. Lista de nombres de personas o cosas.
> 2. f. Conjunto de las voces técnicas propias de una disciplina.

> terminología
>
> 1. f. Conjunto de términos o vocablos propios de determinada profesión, ciencia o materia.

Acepto cualquier otro término, si lo hay, más adecuado.

Comment: Buena pregunta. Intuitivamente, yo solo usaría *nomenclatura* para nombres de objetos, y *terminología* lo vería como un concepto más amplio, que también puede incluir verbos o adjetivos, por ejemplo. Pero esto es solo mi intuición.

Comment: @wimi that is certainly how I would read them too but that may be because that is how the equivalent words are used in English.

Comment: A mi parecer, la terminología puede abarcar varias descripciones para una misma entidad. Por ejemplo, un teclado se puede definir usando terminología informática como un "periférico" o como un "dispositivo de entrada" (se consideran sinónimos). La nomenclatura en cambio pretende que cada entidad posea solo un nombre correcto que lo defina. Por ejemplo, la biología establece códigos explícitos de nomenclatura: zoológico, botánico, de bacterias y de virus. El conejo común es un oryctolagus cuniculus porque así lo define el código de nomenclatura, y no debería haber otro modo de referirse a él.

Comment: Gracias por ambas respuestas. Si bien sigo esperando por una más concluyente, por el momento, me inclino por el término ''terminología''.

Comment: Yo por el contrario encuentro las definiciones bastante claras. Ejemplos en medicina:
**nomenclatura**: cabeza, termómetro, jeringa, amígdala (todas son cosas). **terminología**: cefaléa, termperatura, amigdalítis (todos son términos, no cosas).

Answer (score 2):

Hasta donde yo sé y dentro de mi círculo de personas que conozco, *nomenclatura* lo usamos en general para *símbolos*, mientras que *terminología* para *palabras*. Por ejemplo f'(x) o df(x)/dx serían dos nomenclaturas distintas para expresar la derivada de una función, mientras que 'derivar' y 'diferenciar' serían dos terminologías distintas para la acción de derivar uan función (el último ejemplo es malo porque si bien en algunos contextos significan lo mismo, en general no son lo mismo, pero creo que se entiende a lo que apunto).